# In a pandas data frame can I filter to only show rows which meet a criteria for every column in a data frame with variable number of columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Essentially, I'd like to be able to do something like this to filter a data frame to show only rows where the value in every column is positive:

```
for column in df.columns:
   df = df.loc[flow_df[column]>0,:]
```

but in only one line of code. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
df_neg =df.loc[(df>0).all(axis=1)]
```